# Expo app iOS discribution certificate expired - how do I assign a new one?

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, expo

Its been about a year since I first put my app in the iOS app store.  I have recently got the following message appear in my inbox.

> Your iOS Distribution Certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days

I have tried creating a new distribution certificate in expo-cli, which I have done successfully and now appears in my certificates section on Apple developer, however when I list them the certificates in expo-cli says underneath the new one

> not used by any apps

How do I assign this new certificate with my old app?  Or does it automatically switch when the old one runs out?

Any help would be appreciated, I would really like to keep my app active in the app store when the old cert runs out.

Answer (score 11):

No stress, from the [expo documentation about app signing](https://docs.expo.dev/app-signing/app-credentials/)

> Deleting a distribution certificate **has no effect on any apps already on the App Store**.

#### `eas-cli`

```
eas login
eas credentials
```

```
? Select platform › - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
    Android
❯   iOS
```

```
✔ Do you want to log in to your Apple account? … yes

› Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue
```

```
? Select a Provider ›
    Random profile (123456789)
❯   Company name (123456789)
```

```
? What do you want to do? › - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
❯   Build Credentials: Manage everything needed to build your project
```

```
✔ What do you want to do? › Distribution Certificate: Add a new one to your account
? Generate a new Apple Distribution Certificate? › (Y/n)
```

yes

```
✔ Created Apple distribution certificate
✔ Created distribution certificate
? Do you want application-name to use the new Distribution Certificate? › (Y/n)
```

yes

all done

You can double check the certificates on the:

- Expo dashboard https://expo.dev/accounts/company-name/settings/credentials
- Apple developer https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list

#### `expo-cli` - outdated

You can manage everything from the terminal

```
expo login
expo credentials:manager # or eas credentials
```

```
✔ Select platform › ios
```

And then select **Update Distribution Certificate**

```
? What do you want to do? › - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
    Use existing Push Notifications Key in current project
    Use existing Distribution Certificate in current project
    Remove Provisioning Profile
    Add new Push Notifications Key
    Remove Push Notification credentials
    Update Push Notifications Key
    Add new Distribution Certificate
    Remove Distribution Certificate
❯   Update Distribution Certificate
```

Comment: Feb 2023 here: 
the command needed here has been updated to `eas credentials` and `expo credentials:manager` will not work anymore - you'll receive Apple authentication errors when attempting to actually do anything within the Credentials Manager. Using `eas credentials` seems to work as-intended. 
See: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1677

Answer (score 1):

What I did last year is that I did a new build of the app via the Expo sdk and it prompted me to create a new certificate at that stage.

Comment: Was that when the certificate was already expired?

Answer (score 0):

To assign the new distribution certificate to your app, you need to rebuild your app with the new certificate and re-submit it to the app store. Here are the steps:

```
Open Xcode and go to the "Preferences" tab.
Select "Accounts" and click on your Apple Developer account.
Select "View Details" and find your old distribution certificate.
Click on the "Revoke" button to revoke the old certificate.
Go back to the Apple Developer account and create a new distribution certificate.
Download the new certificate and double-click it to install it on your computer.
Go back to Xcode and select your new certificate from the "Code Signing Identity" section.
Rebuild your app and submit the updated version to the app store.
```

Note that revoking the old certificate and submitting a new version of your app will require you to go through the app review process again.